# How to receive strings from C# in Visual-C++ based .net DLL?

Tags: c#, .net, c++, visual-c++, dll

How to receive strings from C# in Visual-C++ based .net DLL?

In C++ (using clr) I have this code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
##include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

namespace NSST
{
  public ref class Wrapper
  {
 public:
     Wrapper() {}
    static void init_1(std::string a, std::string b){}
     static void init_2(){}
  };
};
```

But in  .net C# I see only one function `init_2`. How do I make `init_1` visible in .net?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use std::string, you should use System::String^:

```
static void init_1(System::String^ a, System::String^ b);
```

Comment: and how to turn System::String^ a into std::string a? is it possible?

Comment: Sure, take a look here: http://buffered.io/2007/03/02/net-systemstring-to-ansi-char/

Comment: Updated link for the said article: http://buffered.io/posts/net-systemstring-to-ansi-char/ (would be great if old comments were editable too).